# Minimal Backup of Fish Shell Config

Tags: backup, fish

Thanks to the influence of many, including one who has a passing association to a certain green tinged distro I have moved over to fish (from zsh).

However config is quite different and I couldn't quite ascertain the answer to the following question. What are the minimum files in my fish config that I need to backup using my dotfile manager?

Bearing in mind I'm very happy to have to install fisher and do a `fisher install` to get my plugins installed again. I know the plugins list is at `~/.config/fish/fish_plugins`, but what about config vars I have set via the `set` command? I assume they would have to be a part of any minimal fish dotfile backup scheme.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is likely to prompt a number of personal responses and that the answer can vary greatly. But you are asking for a *minimum* and so my response is that I have backed up only my config.fish and functions folder and haven't had a need to backup vars.

If you are concerned and want to back up the whole thing, you can back up  the `~/.config/fish` directory, which will include a `fish_variables` file with all your vars.